# Php - Small Content Management (CMS)

Tags: php, content-management-system

I'm having trouble setting up my previously used content management system (CMS) :

**index.php**

```
<?php
?>
<html>                                                                      
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>  
    </td><td width=100% bgcolor="#aaaaaa" valign=top border=1>
        <?php include "content.php" ?>                                      
    </td></tr></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**content.php**

```
<?php
 include "contentids.php";
 $contentid=$_GET['contentid'];
 if(trim($contentid)=="") {
   $contentid=$_POST['contentid'];}

 if($contentfile=$content[$contentid]){
    echo "contentfile = ".$contentfile."<br>";
   include $contentfile;
 }
?>
```

**contentids.php**

```
<?php
 $content['filme']="films.php";
?>
```

**sample from films.php**

```
<center><h1>FILME</h1></center>
<?php
 for ($i=65;$i<=90;$i++) {
$buchstabe=chr($i);
echo "<a href=\"".$PHP_SELF."?contentid=".$contentid."&letter=".$buchstabe."".$sessiontag."\">$buchstabe</a> | ";
}
```

Aways getting following error :

> Undefined index: contentid in C:\My Progs\wamp\www\content.php on line 3, 5 and 7

I have used this system before but I can't find the solution, any hints?

Thanks alot!

Comment: you are this variable ` $contentid=$_GET['contentid'];` but I see nowhere where the GET is finding this information.   I Your form does not define it, and neither do your other files, so the POST variable is giving that notice as well. Typically this will get defined in a form field with `name="contentid"` which is then passed to your URL, and then the GET will take it from there, however (unless you are leaving out some code) it has not been set.

Comment: The system should work without extra forms (should be in url i guess), i just can´t remember how i got this one to work, maybe there is something missing in the contentids.php or content.php

Comment: where is `contentid` coming from in your old files?  (the one in your GET *or* your POST variables?) you seem to be missing a file somewhere.  FYI: *this* is precisely why to comment your code when you write it the first time

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
 include "contentids.php";
 $contentid=isset($_GET['contentid']) ? $_GET['contentid'] : '';
 if(trim($contentid)=="") {
   $contentid=isset($_POST['contentid']) ? $_POST['contentid'] : '';
 }
 if($contentfile=$content[$contentid]){
    echo "contentfile = ".$contentfile."<br>";
   include $contentfile;
 }
?>
```

I have solve your 3 and 5 line problem but in 7 line you are trying to compare string with array and also array key is not possible blank string so it display Undefined index: contentid maby be you can try declaring array like

```
$content = array();
```

Comment: I'd use `!empty` over `isset` then you dont have to check for empty value later.

Comment: @chris85 sometimes `!empty` not work in server so better to use trim